# how the highlighted text color and background is determined

Tags: html, css

how the highlighted text color and background is determined?

I am aware how I can override it - [here](http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/)

I just would like to know how is it determined when not overriding.

Is it based on some other colors used in css?

I am looking to find why the selection color [here](http://www.prowavegroup.ca/2.5/index.php/link2) is a blue one.

FireFox screenshot:
[image]

Comment: For all HTML objects or a specific one? It is generaly determined either by the browser default or by inherited. Depends on the type of object.

Comment: Text selection is determined differently based on the browser

Comment: WhyMe: I am looking to find why the selection color http://www.prowavegroup.ca/2.5/index.php/link2 is a blue one.

Comment: :) Quite slow but I got what you mean now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out..

If I set for :

from background:url(../images/center_bg.jpg)

to background:#fff url(../images/center_bg.jpg)

=> the selection color is like in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

DO the following the the css class:

```
::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #dd2020;
    color: #fff;
}

::selection {
    background-color: #dd2020;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Tested in chrome. Not sure about ie.

From [here](http://www.briangardner.com/text-selection-color/).

In the link you specified they set this ::selection for ff only. Either by javascript or css. It is not the browser default. (Was set in :))

Comment: as I mentioned I am aware how I can override it. The question is how the color is determined? particular example - http://www.prowavegroup.ca/2.5/index.php/link2

Comment: What do you mean determined. Browser default? What in the example am I supposed to see. In chrome it looks the same as normal selection.

Comment: WhyMe: I don't think here http://www.prowavegroup.ca/2.5/index.php/link2 the selection color is browser default..

Comment: WhyMe: please see the screenshot in the question body, it's in FF

Comment: I don't see it like that - I see simple selection. Maybe its OS dependent also but I cant check that. I'm using Win7.

Comment: I am using Win7 + FF 18.0.1 and I get the screenshot above.

Comment: And it's interesting... id I remove all css rules, I will get a classic selection (dark blue)...

Comment: The set it somehow. Its not the default. Either using javascript or css. Oh and I see it now (Downloaded FF)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30661/discussion-between-whyme-and-ihtus)

Comment: I just figured out.. If I set for <div class="center">: from background:url(../images/center_bg.jpg) to background:#fff url(../images/center_bg.jpg) => the selection color is like in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It is the browser default, kind of how the default for a link is blue, and a visited link is purple, it is a long standing convention that the browser makers follow.